# How to create extension which will run my script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I create an Chrome extension, which will add an icon to the toolbar, and when icon clicked, it will run my script:

```
function rewrite() {
janbm_showpass:var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { if (a[i].hasAttribute('type') && a[i].type === 'password') a[i].type = 'text'; } void 0
}
```

It changes stars into text. But the question is how tu run in when icon clicked. I don't want to create any popups and html.

Here is my manifest.json. Is it good?

```
{
"name": "Show password",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "The extension",
"browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "icon.png",

 }, 

"background": {

    "scripts": ["show_pass.js"]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this skeleton, your code has an extra trailing comma

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name": "Show password",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "The extension",
"browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "icon.png"

 }, 

"background": {

    "scripts": ["show_pass.js"]
}
}
```

***show_pass.js***

```
function rewrite() {
//Your stuff here
/*janbm_showpass:var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    if (a[i].hasAttribute('type') && a[i].type === 'password') 
    a[i].type = 'text'; 
} void 0*/
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log("Clicked....");
    rewrite();
});
```